# Unreal installation and storage space requirement

Tags: unreal

I am a new user of Unreal. I installed the program on Windows 7, and after using it for awhile I noticed that the C:/ partition was filling up very fast as I worked on my projects. I store my projects on a storage device different than the one with Windows- does Unreal nevertheless write files related to a project to C:/ and if it does, can such a setting be changed?

I am upgrading to Windows 10. Is there any difference in the behavior explained above between the two Windows versions? Is there any rule of thumb about how much there should be free space on the C:/ partition for Unreal to work with, regardless of where projects are stored?

Comment: Since you're wondering what's suddenly taking your diskspace, this is relevant: https://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free/

Answer (score 2):

What I found is that there was several gigs of data being stored in my **App Data Derived Data Cache**.

```
"C:\Users\yourusername\AppData\Local\UnrealEngine\Common\DerivedDataCache"
```

These are all just cached textures but are way larger than they should be. It is completely safe to delete this derived data cache from your app data (to see this folder you must enable "view hidden options" in your file explorer. When you reopen your project all of your textures will be reset to he default checkered grey but after a while it will recompile them all and that folder will be hopefully be much smaller than what is was before.

This eliminated around 60 gigs off my ssd when I cleared it.

Hopefully this clears up some storage for you.

---

**NOTE**

Reference the unreal guide online to find more info about automatically storing these textures on a external drive as they do explain how to go about doing that on there.